# Does loop back interface generates interrupt on NIC/Hardware

Tags: c, linux, sockets, kernel, nic

Does loop back interface generates interrupt on NIC/Hardware

Comment: "interrupts on the NIC" On which NIC? I have twenty-four.

Comment: Do you think these packets will generate interrupts on a *random* card, or on *all* cards, or on the *first detected* card? What kind of logic could possibly justify any such thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loopback interface is a virtual network interface. It doesn't correspond to any actual hardware, and packets transmitted through it therefore do not generate hardware interrupts.

It's possible that linux has some concept of a "soft interrupt", i.e. an inter-thread/process signalling mechanism, and that packets over the loopback will cause these. Older Linux versions definitely had these "soft interrupts", but I'm not sure if the 2.6 series does, and I'm not sure if packets over the loopback do or ever did generate them.